# 404 Error handling with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php, html, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I use different languages for my site. So the structure is quiet simple:

```
root / => 404.php
       => template_404.php

root/subdir/ =>(language_xy)404.php
```

In my htaccess files I use a redirect to `404.php` in case a page could not be found.

In that `404.php` I use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the entered address that will be echoed to the user.

Depending from the default browser language the `404.php` will be redirect to its subdir folder with the language files.

So it goes like that:

wrong URL entered => redirect to `404.php` => reading out URL and default languages => redirect to language direction `(language_xy)404.php` => loading `template_404.php` from root and echo out wrong URL.

Now the problem is that I would like to have clean URL's like `example.com/langauge_xy/(language_xy)404.php`. Thats why I dont would like to use `$_GET` to send the entered URL to the `(language_xy)404.php`. I thought I could save the entered URL into a SESSION on `404.php` and simply echo out on `template_404.php`. The first time this works but when reloading the page for some reason the content of the SESSION has changed. I have no clue why this happens. The `$_SESSION['url']` is just used once.

So if there is someone who can give me hints on how to solve this issue I really would appreciate.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, or you could create a language file and with one 404.php file you could serve up different content based on the language in the session.

Find the users language: [detect user language in PHP - stable solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493610/detect-user-language-in-php-stable-solution)

Language switching: [Am I breaking any "php good practice" in the following php array which deals with 3 (human) languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329650/am-i-breaking-any-php-good-practice-in-the-following-php-array-which-deals-wit)